# Blogger Javascript with JSON error on Posts > 500

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

I would like to show random posts to my blogger.

I got a javascript from googling and tried it, but the number of random posts are not correct (should be 10 but sometimes 4, sometimes 2, etc). I tried to check what's happening and found out that json.feed.entry [500] throws error.

Here is the javascript that I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function randomposts(json) {
  var randarray = new Array();
  var l=0;
  var flag;
  var numofpost=10;

  var total = parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);

  for(var i=0;i < numofpost;) {
    flag=0;
    randarray.length=numofpost;
    l=Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    for(j in randarray){
      if(l==randarray[j]){
        flag=1;}
    }
    if(flag==0&&l!=0){
      randarray[i++]=l;
    }
  }
  // correct output
  // alert(randarray);

  document.write('<ul>');

  // dummy for testing 500 limit 
  //for (var x = 0; x < numofpost; x++) {
  //  randarray[x]= 495 + x;
  //}

  for(var n in randarray){
    var p=randarray[n];
    var entry=json.feed.entry[p-1];
    var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
    for(var k=0; k < entry.link.length; k++){
      if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){
        document.write('<li> ' + posttitle.link(entry.link[k].href) + '</li>');

      }
    }
  }
  document.write('</ul>');
}
</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index=1&max-results=1000&callback=randomposts" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Currently I set `var total = 500;` so that the random works only for first 500 posts.

How to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**
I added try catch block and the error is *TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined*

**UPDATE 2:**
The following picture is snapshot of console. The json.feed.entry 500 is undefined.
[image: snapshot of console]

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @KemalFadillah: added on last section

Comment: check "entry"..wht r u getting there in the line "var entry=json.feed.entry[p-1];"?

Comment: @Rinku the error clearly says it's `undefined`.

Comment: @KemalFadillah: I had more than 800 posts, and the generated random numbers are correct (below the max).

Comment: all of ur 800+ posts has a title?

Comment: @Rinku: Yes each of them has title

Comment: Title is undefined because the script is looking in the wrong place, try adding ```console.log(json.feed.entry)``` to your script and refactor from that.

Comment: @PHearst: up to array 499, the console shows the object. For array 500 it only shows undefined. See Update 2 on question

Comment: The undefined 500 entry, is probably because of ```var entry=json.feed.entry[p-1];```. But now you see the objects, rewrite your script to make 2 requests (each 500 posts) into a cache, then get x num of random posts from that cache. If you have trouble writing this your self, why not contact the author of the script. Otherwise, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code and markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the feed entry at the randomized index is null, in that case add another condition to ensure that every entry in randomized indexes is not null.

Replace:

```
if(flag==0&&l!=0){
```

with:

```
if(flag==0&&l!=0&&json.feed.entry[l-1]!=null){
  randarray[i++]=l;
}
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Regards,

PP

EDIT:
Then you can call the feed url twice, this is the quick and dirty way to achieve so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=0;
var b=0;
var entries = new Array();
function randomposts(json) {
  for (var i in json.feed.entry) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    if (entry != null) {
        entries[b++] = entry;
    }
  }
  a++;
  if (a < 2) return;
  var randarray = new Array();
  var l=0;
  var flag;
  var numofpost=10;

  var total = entries.length;

  for(var i=0;i < numofpost;) {
    flag=0;
    randarray.length=numofpost;
    l=Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    for(j in randarray){
      if(l==randarray[j]){
        flag=1;}
    }
    if(flag==0&&l!=0){
      randarray[i++]=l;
      //alert(l);
    }
  }
  // correct output
  // alert(randarray);

  document.write('<ul>');

  // dummy for testing 500 limit 
  //for (var x = 0; x < numofpost; x++) {
  //  randarray[x]= 495 + x;
  //}

  for(var n in randarray){
    var p=randarray[n];
    var entry=entries[p-1];
    var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
    for(var k=0; k < entry.link.length; k++){
      if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){
        document.write('<li> ' + posttitle.link(entry.link[k].href) + '</li>');

      }
    }
  }
  document.write('</ul>');
}
</script>

<script src="/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index=1&max-results=500&callback=randomposts" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index=501&max-results=500&callback=randomposts" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your update is only workaround, which will give similar result if I set the total posts as 500.

Comment: Using two feeds seems working. Would you please explain how it works? And is there any down performance?

Comment: As the answer provided by Kemal Fadillah, google restricts the number of returned feeds to 500, but you can change the range of feeds you want to get by start-index param. So what the script does is to request two sets of 500 feeds (1-500 & 501-1000). Both request has a same callback which is randomposts() which waits for responds of two requests. Once both responds arrive, it will be put into an array and after that it is pretty much similar to your original code. I don't think it has significantly lower performance.

Answer (score 1):

While you set the `max-results` to 1000, the entries returned from the server will be capped to 500. It will still return the right total number of entries, however, as you can see if you access `json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t`.

[Source](https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/79626?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. While it may be the root of the problem, it does not solve my problem. I'll try work around and waiting for other answers first before give up :D

Comment: Well you can try to make your function generates a random number inclusively between 0 and 499 (or 1 - 500 if it's 1-based). But then again, that's basically what you're doing as a workaround right now. I don't see any other way, to be honest. But maybe that's just me being obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Google JavaScript Client Library - Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts#resource-representations) to retrieve posts of a blog.

**See the following example:**

```
  <script>
  function renderResults(response) {
    if (response.items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        //do whatever you want with the posts of your blog
      }      
    }
    if(response.nextPageToken) {
      var blogId = 'XXX Your blogId XXX';
      var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
        'blogId': blogId,
        'pageToken': response.nextPageToken,
        'maxResults': 100,
      });
      request.execute(renderResults);
    }
  }
  function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('XXX Get your API Key from https://code.google.com/apis/console XXX');
    gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v3', function() {
        var blogId = 'XXX Your blogId XXX';
        var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
          'blogId': blogId,
          'maxResults': 100,
        });
        request.execute(renderResults);        
    });
  }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blogger capped maximum number of entries per request to 500, even though it's not documented it's evidently so. If you want to get all your entries you have to re-build your feed chunk by chunk setting `start-index` property: `/feeds/posts/default?start-index=501`.
Here you may find a bit more information: http://too-clever-by-half.blogspot.ru/2011/12/blog-feed-500-post-limit-for-more-than.html