# Number Page Navigation showing Last 500 Posts Instead of 10000 posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, blogger

Thanks in Advance to helping my problem.

I have 10,000 Pages in my Blogger Site and using following HTML code to show Number page navigation on main page

Here my issue is, there are morethan 10,000 posts but it uses first 500 posts and showing 18 pages (it should be more than 300+ pages)

I changes 28 posts / page and as it showing 18 x 28 pages = 500 or less

When i have 10,000 posts it should show 28 posts x 350+ pages

You can have a Look on : [Dealdimer.com](http://www.dealdimer.com)

Please someone guide me where the issue is, Sorry if i'm poor in explaining my concern.

My Code as:

```html
<style type="text/CSS">
.showpageArea a { 
text-decoration:underline; 
} 
.showpageNum a { 
text-decoration:none; 
border: 1px solid #7AA1C3; 
margin:0 3px; 
padding:3px; 
} 
.showpageNum a:hover { 
border: 1px solid #7AA1C3; 
background-color:#F6F6F6; 
} 
.showpagePoint { 
color:#333; 
text-decoration:none; 
border: 1px solid #7AA1C3; 
background: #F6F6F6; 
margin:0 3px; 
padding:3px; 
} 
.showpageOf { 
text-decoration:none; 
padding:3px; 
margin: 0 3px 0 0; 
} 
.showpage a { 
text-decoration:none; 
border: 1px solid #7AA1C3; 
padding:3px; 
} 
.showpage a:hover { 
text-decoration:none; 
} 
.showpageNum a:link,.showpage a:link { 
text-decoration:none; 
color:#7AA1C3; 
} 
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function showpageCount(json) { 
var thisUrl = location.href; 
var htmlMap = new Array(); 
var isFirstPage = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.length-5,thisUrl.length)==".com/"; 
var isLablePage = thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/")!=-1; 
var isPage = thisUrl.indexOf("/search?updated")!=-1; 
var thisLable = isLablePage ? thisUrl.substr(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/")+14,thisUrl.length) : "";
thisLable = thisLable.indexOf("?")!=-1 ? thisLable.substr(0,thisLable.indexOf("?")) : thisLable; 
var thisNum = 1; 
var postNum=1; 
var itemCount = 0; 
var fFlag = 0; 
var eFlag = 0; 
var html= ''; 
var upPageHtml =''; 
var downPageHtml ='';
var pageCount = 28; 
var displayPageNum = 5; 
var upPageWord = 'Previous'; 
var downPageWord = 'Next';
var labelHtml = '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/search/label/'+thisLable+'?&max-results='+pageCount+'">';
for(var i=0, post; post = json.feed.entry[i]; i++) { 
var timestamp = post.published.$t.substr(0,10); 
var title = post.title.$t; 
if(isLablePage){ 
if(title!=''){ 
if(post.category){ 
for(var c=0, post_category; post_category = post.category[c]; c++) { 
if(encodeURIComponent(post_category.term)==thisLable){ 
if(itemCount==0 || (itemCount % pageCount ==(pageCount-1))){ 
if(thisUrl.indexOf(timestamp)!=-1 ){ 
thisNum = postNum; 
}
postNum++; 
htmlMap[htmlMap.length] = '/search/label/'+thisLable+'?updated-max='+timestamp+'T00%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00&max-results='+pageCount; 
} 
} 
} 
}//end if(post.category){
itemCount++; 
}
}else{ 
if(title!=''){ 
if(itemCount==0 || (itemCount % pageCount ==(pageCount-1))){ 
if(thisUrl.indexOf(timestamp)!=-1 ){ 
thisNum = postNum; 
}
if(title!='') postNum++; 
htmlMap[htmlMap.length] = '/search?updated-max='+timestamp+'T00%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00&max-results='+pageCount; 
} 
} 
itemCount++; 
} 
}
for(var p =0;p< htmlMap.length;p++){ 
if(p>=(thisNum-displayPageNum-1) && p<(thisNum+displayPageNum)){ 
if(fFlag ==0 && p == thisNum-2){ 
if(thisNum==2){ 
if(isLablePage){ 
upPageHtml = labelHtml + upPageWord +'</a></span>'; 
}else{ 
upPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"><a href="/">'+ upPageWord +'</a></span>'; 
} 
}else{ 
upPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"><a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ upPageWord +'</a></span>'; 
}
fFlag++; 
}
if(p==(thisNum-1)){ 
html += '<span class="showpagePoint">'+thisNum+'</span>'; 
}else{ 
if(p==0){ 
if(isLablePage){ 
html = labelHtml+'1</a></span>'; 
}else{ 
html += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/">1</a></span>';
} 
}else{ 
html += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ (p+1) +'</a></span>'; 
} 
}
if(eFlag ==0 && p == thisNum){ 
downPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"> <a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ downPageWord +'</a></span>'; 
eFlag++; 
} 
}//end if(p>=(thisNum-displayPageNum-1) && p<(thisNum+displayPageNum)){ 
}//end for(var p =0;p< htmlMap.length;p++){
if(thisNum>1){ 
if(!isLablePage){ 
html = ''+upPageHtml+' '+html +' '; 
}else{ 
html = ''+upPageHtml+' '+html +' '; 
} 
}
html = '<div class="showpageArea"><span style="COLOR: #000;" class="showpageOf"> Pages ('+(postNum-1)+')</span>'+html;
if(thisNum<(postNum-1)){ 
html += downPageHtml;
}
if(postNum==1) postNum++; 
html += '</div>';
if(isPage || isFirstPage || isLablePage){ 
var pageArea = document.getElementsByName("pageArea"); 
var blogPager = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
if(postNum <= 2){ 
html =''; 
}
for(var p =0;p< pageArea.length;p++){ 
pageArea[p].innerHTML = html; 
}
if(pageArea&&pageArea.length>0){ 
html =''; 
}
if(blogPager){ 
blogPager.innerHTML = html; 
} 
}
} 
</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=showpageCount&max-results=99999" ; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Did you check this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917058/blogger-javascript-with-json-error-on-posts-500?rq=1

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem, does the `summary` script return all results? If not, the problem is there and not in the code you posted.

Comment: It already set to max 99,999, you can see end of script (complete code i'h provided)  -in-script&callback=showpageCount&max-results=99999"

Comment: @briosheje I think it the same related to me but i couldn't find if(flag==0&&l!=0){ Code in my script to replace. .. Is that the following code same?   if(fFlag ==0 && p == thisNum-2){ 
if(thisNum==2){

Comment: Hello, please help - I'm struck for the solution.....